# Creating and uploading PIC in GCC

Tags: gcc, linker, microcontroller, gnu-assembler, position-independent-code

Suppose I wish to create position independent code which will be dynamically loaded by a MCU.

GCC allows for compiling PIC but I am unsure what the process is to get the final binary output.

To clarify, suppose I have implemented a C function which is self contained(no global var). I have a separate RTOS on my MCU which will downloaded this function and run it at a specific address.

What is the process for compiling this function and getting the binary image to upload to the MCU? What would my linker script look like in this case?